# Evaluate $\frac{3}{4}s_*=\sum_0^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}$ from known $s_*$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $$s_*=\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$ show $$\frac{3}{4}s_*=\sum_0^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}$$

This is homework and i have no idea how to get into the right direction. I was looking for a rearrangement of $s_*$ from which i could show the desired result but i had no luck. 
I would be happy about any tips - no full solutions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** The second sum ranges over all odd numbers. How does this relate to the sum over all even numbers?

Answer (score 1):

$$s_*=\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^2}+\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}= \frac{1}{4}\sum_1^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}+\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$$
Hence
$$s_*=\frac{1}{4}s_*+\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$$